# AWS - private EC2(N. Virginia) & S3(Mumbai) - list issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Have created a private EC2 instance, created a VPC Endpoint for S3 (com.amazonaws.us-east-1.s3), I am able to fetch S3 bucket files which are there in us-east-1 region.

```
aws s3 ls s3://usbastiontesting --recursive
```

I have an S3 bucket in Mumbai region, is there anyway i can get those files from the private EC2 instance (N. Virginia)?

Used below command, but it's not fetching files:

```
aws s3 ls s3://mumbaibastiontesting --recursive --region ap-south-1
```

Throwing below Error:

```
2018-06-12 11:09:42,874 - MainThread - botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - INFO - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
2018-06-12 11:10:42,938 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - ConnectionError received when sending HTTP request.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 213, in _get_response
    proxies=self.proxies, timeout=self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/adapters.py", line 419, in send
    raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /mumbaibastiontesting?prefix=&encoding-type=url (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<botocore.awsrequest.AWSHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f8fe99f86d0>, 'Connection to s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com timed out. (connect timeout=60)'))
```

please suggest.

Comment: *"It's not fetching files"* but what is happening?  An error?  A timeout?  What does `--debug` tell you?

Comment: Throws ConnectionError error. Updated original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Endpoints doesn't support cross region access. if you refer the AWS Documentation For [Endpoints for S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-endpoints-s3.html) it's clearly mentioned

> Endpoints currently do not support cross-region requests—ensure that you create your endpoint in the same region as your bucket.

Comment: Thanks for the info.